Self-answering questions - acceptable on Quant or not?
Coming from SO, and majoring in quantitative finance, I have spent the past day reading through some of the awesome questions/answers in this community. I feel as though there are  a couple canonical questions however that, while directly relating to quants, have yet to be asked or canonically addressed on the site. I know that on SO or MSE for instance, self-answered questions can be encouraged if they provide value, so I was wondering if the younger community here has any admonitions against them (should they be great questions/answers, of course). 

I think there is no restriction about self-answering.
It is not so common in quant.SE, but sometimes users self-answer to their own question and nobody prohibited that behavior or something like that.
Of course, wait for some answer given by some older and more expert user than me! :)

Agreed, no problem whatsoever with self-answering. I do believe that the community will hold you to a higher standard though.

Thanks for the feedback! I would imagine so, if I do do a few they'll have ample amounts of effort in them :)

You're welcome @DonkeyKong!
